# Strange attributes appear inside html tags

Tags: c#, html, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using ASP.NET Core. I've create a Razor page with HTML markup, and just run it in VS 2022. And I see this:

[image: screenshot of issue]

I thought it was an ASP.NET Core feature, perhaps, but I checked my old project - there is no such problem.

Comment: please post code as text, not as images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by the .NET CSS isolation feature, which was originally intended for Blazor:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-7.0

However, it has also been added to .NET MVC as well. Further reading: https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/355/css-isolation-in-razor-pages

Comment: Long story short, these things are normal?

Comment: Yes, normal behaviour.